# JavaScript кнопка удаления конкретного элемента со страницы и LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, input, localstorage

Как можно реализовать кнопку удаления при нажатии на кнопку рядом с отзывом, чтобы данный отзыв удалялся со страницы и из LocalStorage?

Также попытался реализовать функцию, которая открывает/скрывает все оставленные отзывы к товарам, но как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на текст "Гиря" "Болт" открывались отзывы только к конкретному товару, а не ко всем, как у меня?

HTML

```
<form>
        <label>
            <span>Товар</span>
            <input id='product-name'/>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Комментарий</span>
            <input id='product-comment'/>
        </label>
        <button>Добавить</button>
    </form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="more-potato">Гиря</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="more-onion">Болт</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

JS

```
const item = document.getElementById('product-name');
const reviews = document.getElementById('product-comment');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let obj = localStorage.getItem('obj') 
    obj = obj || '{}'
    obj = JSON.parse(obj)
    const oi = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li')
    oi.forEach(o => {
        const ol = document.createElement('ol')
        o.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', ol)
        const v = o.querySelector('span').textContent
        obj[v]?.forEach(newReviews => {
            ol.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${newReviews}</li>`)
        })

        ol.style.display = 'none';

        const potatoBtn = document.querySelector(".more-potato");
        potatoBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (ol.style.display === 'none') {
                ol.style.display = 'inline';
            } else {
                ol.style.display = 'none';
            }
        })

        const onionBtn = document.querySelector(".more-onion");
        onionBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (ol.style.display === 'none') {
                ol.style.display = 'inline';
            } else {
                ol.style.display = 'none';
            }
        })
    });
    
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', el => {
        el.preventDefault()
        const newItem = item.value
        const newReviews = reviews.value
        if (newItem == '' || newReviews == '') return
        obj[newItem] = obj[newItem] ?? []
        obj[newItem].push(newReviews)
        localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(obj)) 
        el.target.reset()
        oi.forEach(o => {
            const v = o.querySelector('span').textContent
            if (v != newItem) return
            o.querySelector('ol').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 
                `
                    <li>${newReviews}</li>
                    <button id='clear-btn'>Удалить</button>
                `)
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Начать можно с того, что ИД на странице должно быть уникальным. Продолжить можно тем, что для решения вопроса нужно предоставлять не всю свою программу а только нужную часть. Т.е., в твоем случае, html и css (если он есть).

Comment: Вам надо структурировать само хранилище, например, что бы это был объект с ключами по ID товара, а значения - массив комментариев. При добавлении передавать ид товара, при удалении id товара и какой то идентификатор комментария. При удалении методом filter можно воспользоваться. Далее запускать функцию отрисовки обновленных комментариев.

Answer (score 0):

> Как можно реализовать кнопку удаления при нажатии на кнопку рядом с отзывом, чтобы данный отзыв удалялся со страницы и из LocalStorage?

> Также попытался реализовать функцию, которая открывает/скрывает все оставленные отзывы к товарам, но как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на текст "Гиря" "Болт" открывались отзывы только к конкретному товару, а не ко всем, как у меня?

Все это можно организовать как-то так...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-theme='light'>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
ol {
    display: none;
}
.on ol {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
    let obj = localStorage.getItem('obj') 
    obj = obj || '{}'
    obj = JSON.parse(obj)
    const oi = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li')
    oi.forEach(o => {
        const ol = document.createElement('ol')
        o.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', ol)
        const v = o.querySelector('.item').textContent
        obj[v]?.forEach(t => {
            ol.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', comment(t))
        })
    })
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const k = item.value
        const t = text.value
        if (k == '' || t == '') return
        const id = (new Date()).toString()
        const oc = {id, txt: t}
        obj[k] = obj[k] ?? []
        obj[k].push(oc)
        save() 
        e.target.reset()
        oi.forEach(o => {
            const v = o.querySelector('span').textContent
            if (v != k) return
            o.querySelector('ol').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', comment(oc))
            o.classList.add('on')
        })
    })
    const ou = document.querySelector('ul')
    ou.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const o = e.target
        if (!o.classList.contains('item')) return
        o.closest('li').classList.toggle('on')
    })
    ou.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const o = e.target
        if (o.tagName != 'BUTTON') return
        const ol = o.closest('[data-id]')
        if (!ol) return
        const id = ol.dataset.id
        const v = ol.closest('ol').closest('li').querySelector('span').textContent
        obj[v] = obj[v].filter(o => o.id != id)
        save()
        ol.remove()
    })
    //
    function save() {
        localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(obj))
    }
    //
    function comment(o) {
        return `<li data-id='${o.id}'><span>${o.txt}</span> <button>Удалить</button></li>`
    }
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label>
        <span>Товар</span>
        <input id='item' />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Комментарий</span>
        <input id='text' />
    </label>
    <button>Добавить</button>
</form>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class='item'>Картошка</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='item'>Лук</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```